# I want the android screens like this the upper trapeziam shape and the picture should be changed dynamically

Tags: android, xml, shapes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QzUe.png)`

```
<!-- Colored rectangle-->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="50dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FAD55C" />
    </shape>
</item>



<!-- These rectangles for the right side -->


<item
    android:top="63dp"
    android:bottom="-40dp"
    android:right="-25dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-42">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

`[image]

i want to make the trapezium like this shown at upper half please help me in making this screen i will be very  greatfull to this

Comment: Post code which you try

Comment: Stackoverflow is not to get free code done for us, is to help us when we're stuck. You can easily build that in a RelativeLayout just with xml

Comment: i said i want the trapezium shape that is shown above for the imageview if you cant help then you don't need to comment @KrishnaJ

Comment: You cant get ready code from this..without knowing your try how can we help

Comment: i want xml coding i have posted the coding please try that

Comment: is a vector asset an acceptable answer or you want xml "<shape>"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want a vector drawable: trapezium.xml

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="300.0"
android:viewportWidth="480.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#E03825" android:pathData="M-18.93,275.26l505.01,-264.25l145.36,277.8l-505.01,264.25z"/>
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M-33.8,289.15L493,3.68"
    android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="14"/>
```

EDIT

then you can put it in front of an imageview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.lcimi.myapplication.MainActivity">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/back"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/trapezium"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/front"
        android:layout_height="300dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

to get somthing like this http://imgur.com/a/CMfON

Comment: actully i want to cut the screen into two half in one half there will be image and in second other text and details so either if there is xml to make lower half or upper half any one could work

Comment: i eddited my answer to use it inside a layout, is that enough?

Comment: what height should be given to upper imageview